# Logistic regression for a text feature

Tags: machine-learning, octave, logistic-regression

As far I know, we can apply logistic regression for numerical values. What if I have a text feature which I should reject (0) or approve (1)?

For instance:
[Feature  y]
Text1 1
Text2 0
Text3 0
...
Textn 1

What kind of approach should I use?

Comment: represent the features as numerical values. One of the most common model is [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) and--the recent one is--[word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec)

Comment: The feature  you propose seems to be a binary bag of word. thus you can apply LR to this feature. Is your question "how to implement LR in octave given a binary BoW feature" ?

Comment: Yes you guys nailed it, it's exactly what I need. Do you know if there's a ready to use implementation for BoW?